# Invalid swagger request path

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springdoc

I am using springdoc and trying to configure swagger at my project. I have an auth endpoint and want to perform request at swagger ui page.
Swagger correctly shows endpoint path: `/api/v1/auth`, but when I trying to perform request at "Try it out" menu it sends request to `http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs/localhost/api/v1/auth`.

Here is the example:

[image: Swagger correctly shows endpoint path]

[image: Invalid url]

Here is my curl connection string generated in swagger:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs/localhost/api/v1/auth' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "username": "string",
  "password": "string"
}'
```

And configuration beans:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi publicUserApi() {
        return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
                .group("Api")
                .pathsToMatch("/api/**")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenApi() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info().title("Application API"))
                .servers(List.of(new Server().url("localhost").description("Server")));
    }
}
```

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the server URL that's shown in the Swagger-UI?

Comment: @Debargha Roy, sure [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/gFPRRaI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the fact that you are setting the server URL as `localhost` and not `http://localhost`

When you're specifying the path without a protocol, it's always taken to be the relative path from the current URL of the page, which in this case is `http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs`.

Updating your OpenAPI Bean to reflect the URL with protocol should solve the problem.

```java
@Bean
public OpenAPI customOpenApi() {
    return new OpenAPI()
            .info(new Info().title("Application API"))
            .servers(List.of(new Server().url("http://localhost:8080").description("Server")));
}
```

I have specified the port number explicitly as `8080` for the sake of clarity.